How do I fix the placholders positioning in bootstrap5
Im trying to build a registration form and right now the spacing/positioning is kinda whack.
How should I fix them to be in the same line/row?
symmetrical.
I added the code, and a photo of how it looks like.


<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form>     
     <!--First Name-->
     <div class="mb-3 mt-3">
         <label for="fname" class="form-label">First name:</label>
         <input type="fname" class="form-control-xs" id="fname" placeholder="Enter name" />
     </div>
     <!--Last name-->
     <div class="mb-3 mt-3">
         <label for="lname" class="form-label">Lastname:</label>
         <input type="lname" class="form-control-xs" id="lname" placeholder="Last name" />
     </div>
     <!--Email-->
     <div class="mb-3 mt-3">
         <label for="email" class="form-label">E-mail:</label>
         <input type="email" class="form-control-xs" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
     </div>
     <!--Country-->
     <div class="mb-3 mt-3">
         <label for="city" class="form-label">City of residence:</label>
         <input type="city" class="form-control-xs" id="city" placeholder="City" />
     </div>
     <!--Button-->
     <input type="submit" value="Register" />
     <!--mandatory check box-->
     <input class='acb' type='checkbox' name='acheckbox[]' value='1' onclick='deRequire("acb")' required>By checking this box you agree to the
     <!--TERMS OF USE-->
     <a href="useragreement.html">user agreement</a>
     <!--PARAGRAPH-->
     <p>If you click the "Register" button, the form-data will be sent to the owner of the website.</p>
     <p>Already have an account?</p>
     <a href="../sign in/login.html"><button type="button">Sign In</button></a>
     

 </form>



enter image description here
I want it to be in the same line/row symmetrical sorry for grammar mistakes.

remove margin-bottom of label.form-label

You can check bootstrap documentation. It contains many examples. It also has an example for you problem. Anyway here is the answer.
Link for the documentation:
Bootstrap documentation



* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
    color: #272727;
}

.register-form {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

form {
    width: 30%;
}

.form-group {
    margin-top: 5px !important;
}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="register-form">
        <form>
            <!--First Name-->
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="fname" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">First name:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="fname" class="form-control" id="fname" placeholder="Enter name" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--Last name-->
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="lname" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Last Name:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="lname" class="form-control" id="lname" placeholder="Last name" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--Email-->
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="email" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">E-mail:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <!--Country-->
            <div class="form-group row">
                <label for="city" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">City of residence:</label>
                <div class="col-sm-8">
                    <input type="city" class="form-control" id="city" placeholder="City" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>




Would you mind to send me where can I learn more about this CSS
And how did you know to do it

{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
color: #272727;
}

.register-form {
width: 100%;
height: 100vh;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
align-items: center;
flex-direction: column;
}
form {
width: 30%;
}
.form-group {
margin-top: 5px !important;
}

First of all, if you don't know css I prefer you should start to learn css before work with bootstrap. But it's not mandatory, it will help you to understand bootstrap well.
I will tell you how I learned css. I learned basic things about css from you tube. There were bunch of tutorials there. Then you can search you tube for html, css websites. I learned from "Easy Tutorials" channel. I do coding with the you tube video. When I couldn't understand something I search and learned more about it from google (documentries). Also you can easily aks from chatgpt.

Now I'm going to tell how fixed your error. I just simply go through the bootstrap documentation which is given in my answer. Then I use bootstrap classes to get needed output.

Use display: grid and grid-template-columns: subgrid:


.form-inputs {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  gap: 16px;
  align-items: center;
  label {
    margin: 0;
  }
  &>div{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: subgrid;
    grid-column: span 2;
  }
}
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
<form>     
    <div class="form-inputs">
       <!--First Name-->
       <div class="mb-3 mt-3">
           <label for="fname" class="form-label">First name:</label>
           <input type="fname" class="form-control-xs" id="fname" placeholder="Enter name" />
       </div>
       <!--Last name-->
       <div class="mb-3 mt-3">
           <label for="lname" class="form-label">Lastname:</label>
           <input type="lname" class="form-control-xs" id="lname" placeholder="Last name" />
       </div>
       <!--Email-->
       <div class="mb-3 mt-3">
           <label for="email" class="form-label">E-mail:</label>
           <input type="email" class="form-control-xs" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
       </div>
       <!--Country-->
       <div class="mb-3 mt-3">
           <label for="city" class="form-label">City of residence:</label>
           <input type="city" class="form-control-xs" id="city" placeholder="City" />
       </div>
     </div>
     <!--Button-->
     <input type="submit" value="Register" />
     <!--mandatory check box-->
     <input class='acb' type='checkbox' name='acheckbox[]' value='1' onclick='deRequire("acb")' required>By checking this box you agree to the
     <!--TERMS OF USE-->
     <a href="useragreement.html">user agreement</a>
     <!--PARAGRAPH-->
     <p>If you click the "Register" button, the form-data will be sent to the owner of the website.</p>
     <p>Already have an account?</p>
     <a href="../sign in/login.html"><button type="button">Sign In</button></a>
     

 </form>



